# Customizing ADV Data in Beacons To include Personal Messages

Tags: ios, ios7, ibeacon

I Have a requirement for My beacon to transmit a Personal message or a string When iOS Devices are in Range and the iOS device has to display that string.

i know some beacon companies allow customizing option. So i would like to know if any of Beacon company is offering such a service.

So kindly guide me in this and tell if it is available.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the iOS CoreLocation APIs to locate beacons based on iBeacon technology, then this is not possible.  The APIs force you to specify the 16 byte identifier up front of any beacon you wish to detect.  This leaves only four readable bytes in the advertisement.

Two options for your requirement:

1. Use the remaining four bytes as a key to a longer message stored in a web service.  My company makes a service called ProximityKit that does exactly this.
2. Build your own custom beacon and read the advertising data with CoreBluetooth APIs.  You will still be very limited in space due to Bluetooth LE advertising packet size constraints, but you could get about 20 bytes to store your message.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the remaining four bytes concept.What data can be transmitted with it.Can i send for example a string and what is the maximum character size that i can send. Can you please also tell more about proximity kit and give a example.

Comment: There are two fields you can put data into, "major" (2 bytes) and "minor" (2 bytes).  So if you send 8-bit characters, that is only enough room for four characters.  You can see an example of Proximiy Kit in use here: http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/proximitykit/webbeacon/  Look for the part where it says "Then add a 'url' attribute".  This would be the mechanism you would use to tie a personal message or string to the beacon.

Comment: How can we add services and characteristics in Beacon Device. Is there any Desktop application to add services and characteristics or it customized only by the hardware manufacturer.
Can we build our own Beacon device to include Services and Characteristics.